# How to connect windows phone app to use database stored in sql azure

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

How to Connect Windows Phone 7 app To use Database Stored In SQL Azure...

Comment: Go to this link. Data from Cloud on Windows Phone http://debugmode.net/2012/01/11/data-from-cloud-on-windows-phone/

Comment: This link also shows how to make the DB, webservice and wp7 client in four steps
[Windows Phone-Azure Tutorial](http://breathingtech.com/2011/how-to-use-wcf-services-to-access-sql-azure-database-from-windows-phone-7-app-part-1/)

Answer (score 2):

Use a WCF Service to access SQL Azure Database from Windows Phone 7.
Tutorial : http://mobile.dzone.com/news/how-use-wcf-services-access